# vista que muestre un mensaje en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

hola como puedo hacer que mi vista me muestre un mensaje de que cuando no exista un pago me muestre un mensaje de que esta pendiente, la tabla que tengo en pago y tiene id, monto, fecha y idSolicitud

esta es mi vista dentro de lo que llevo

```
create view vista_pago as 
select Monto,Fecha from Pago where  id<0='Pendiente';
```

Comment: Saludos. Cual es el error que se le muestra o el resultado erróneo (es decir que espera y que obtiene); me salta la duda ¿que resultado quiere recibir/evaluar con ` where  id<0='Pendiente`? Por que `Pendiete` debe ser una columna (entre el `select` y el `from`) asumiendo que los registros con `id=0` así los clasificara como pendiente.

Comment: esque lo que intento hacer esque me muestre todos los datos pero cuando no exista uno me debe mandar un mensaje de que esta pendiente pero no logro que me de ese mensaje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para estos menesteres puedes usar CASE de MySQL
[MySQL uso de Case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)
en tu caso quedaría algo asi como:

```
SELECT  
     Monto,
     Fecha,
     CASE 
       WHEN id<0 THEN 'Pendiente'
       WHEN id=0 THEN 'Pagado'
       WHEN id=1 THEN 'Anulado'
     END AS estado
FROM Pago WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```

Solo un consejo, deberías agregar un campo a tu tabla que indique el status del pago y no usar el id, el cual generalmente se usa solo como identificador.

saludos.